# Autosize Web browser with Form

Tags: vb.net, browser

When form size is changed,webbrowser must change automatically with the form.
That is possible?
Sorry my english by the way.
if you need the code tell me i wil put him here.

Comment: Have a look at the Anchor Property of the WebBrowser Control.

Comment: Google it: .net anchor property